# how to add apostrophe to elements in list which dont have it using Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings and integers which are separated by commas however the integers dont have an apostrophe which I need. You can see some of the elements dont have the ''. Can someone help me put this in? thanks!

['BZ60830', 'BFEP3N8', 6039644, 'VNG6273', 56855557, 'B3SZGR6', 5575758, 'BYWJRH8']

Comment: Did you try converting the integers to strings?

Comment: The commas aren't part of the list; that's just how a list is displayed. Your issue is that you have a list that contains `str` objects and `int` objects, and you want to replace the `int` elements with `str` representations of them.

Comment: @glibdud yeap - df1 = df['Numbers'].tolist() and then string = str(df1) and the output is still = ['BZ60830', 'BFEP3N8', 6039644, 'VNG6273', 56855557, 'B3SZGR6', 5575758, 'BYWJRH8']

Comment: That's because you created a string representation of the entire list. That gave you a string whose first three characters are `[`, `'`, and `B`. You clearly want a list of strings, not a string of a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = ['BZ60830', 'BFEP3N8', 6039644, 'VNG6273', 56855557, 'B3SZGR6', 5575758, 'BYWJRH8']
data = [str(item) for item in data ]
print (data)
```

output:

```
['BZ60830', 'BFEP3N8', '6039644', 'VNG6273', '56855557', 'B3SZGR6', '5575758', 'BYWJRH8']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either `map` type `str` to your list

```
list(map(str, lst))
```

**Alternative** as suggested by [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) without checking the type

```
lst_new = [str(i) for i in lst]
```

Comment: Why bother checking the type? `str(s) == s`

Comment: @chepner : Thanks for the comment. I added your suggestion

Comment: @Sheldore Actually, I think he was just suggesting `[str(i) for i in lst]`.

Comment: @glibdud : That is equivalent to my first answer I think

Comment: great this worked - I have a question however and sorry if its silly but im still new to pyhton. when I convert the list to a string by ```str(list)``` and then i print the string it doesn't give me the '' around the numbers. do you know why? it seems like your code is doing the same thing but yours works!

Comment: That's not what I suggested. You don't need to check if `i` is a string before calling `str(i)`, because you are going to get the same (or an equivalent) string back (just as when you simply used `map(str, lst)` instead of `map(lambda x: x if <somecheck> else str(i), lst)`.

Comment: @Zack : when you do `str(list)`, you are passing the whole list to `str`. You need to map the `str` function to all the individual elements of the list, which is done as I showed above either using `map` or using list comprehension

Comment: The one with the check, yes. The alternative is fine.